# Error starting angular with docker compose

Tags: angular, docker

I'm trying to up an angular project with docker but appears this error and I don't know how to solve it.

```
Attaching to industrialareas_angular_ctnr
industrialareas_angular_ctnr | 
industrialareas_angular_ctnr | > project@0.0.0 start /usr/src/app
industrialareas_angular_ctnr | > ng serve --host 0.0.0.0
industrialareas_angular_ctnr | 
industrialareas_angular_ctnr | An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/build-angular/package.json'
industrialareas_angular_ctnr | Require stack:
industrialareas_angular_ctnr | - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/node/node-modules-architect-host.js
industrialareas_angular_ctnr | - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/node/index.js
industrialareas_angular_ctnr | - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/architect-command.js
industrialareas_angular_ctnr | - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/commands/serve-impl.js
industrialareas_angular_ctnr | - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/tools/export-ref.js
industrialareas_angular_ctnr | - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/tools/index.js
industrialareas_angular_ctnr | - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/utilities/json-schema.js
industrialareas_angular_ctnr | - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/command-runner.js
industrialareas_angular_ctnr | - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/cli/index.js
industrialareas_angular_ctnr | - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/init.js
industrialareas_angular_ctnr | - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng
industrialareas_angular_ctnr | See "/tmp/ng-91Jx0T/angular-errors.log" for further details.
industrialareas_angular_ctnr | npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
industrialareas_angular_ctnr | npm ERR! syscall spawn
industrialareas_angular_ctnr | npm ERR! file sh
industrialareas_angular_ctnr | npm ERR! errno ENOENT
industrialareas_angular_ctnr | npm ERR! project@0.0.0 start: `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0`
industrialareas_angular_ctnr | npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
industrialareas_angular_ctnr | npm ERR! 
industrialareas_angular_ctnr | npm ERR! Failed at the project@0.0.0 start script.
industrialareas_angular_ctnr | npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
industrialareas_angular_ctnr | 
industrialareas_angular_ctnr | npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
industrialareas_angular_ctnr | npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-02-09T11_08_03_642Z-debug.log
```

I have an angular docker service

docker-compose.yml: (updated without volume)

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  angular:
    container_name: industrialareas_angular_ctnr
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-angular
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 4200:4200
```

With this docker image for angular

Dockerfile-angular:

```
FROM node:14
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY ./project/package*.json .
RUN npm i
RUN npm i -g @angular/cli@12.2.8
COPY ./project .
RUN npm build
EXPOSE 4200
CMD npm start
```

But now appears errors that packages are not installed:

> industrialareas_angular_ctnr | Could not find the '@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server' builder's node package.

Anybody could help me please ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you check the log at `/root/.npm/_logs/2022-02-09T11_08_03_642Z-debug.log` ? can you provide its detail ?

Comment: I don't know how to access to docker logs files.

Comment: The Compose file `volumes:` are hiding the `node_modules` directory from the image build.  Delete that block.